# openshift java - debug error in console

Tags: java, web, openshift

I create a openshift java webproject under Eclipse. When I run, it doesn't show me debug error on my console. Can someone tell me how can I fix that ? Maybe log4j, but I don't know how it works. Help please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your logger to print to console? Check the appenders in log4j.properties or log4j.xml file to see if yoo have attached a console appender.

Comment: This should be a comment. Also, the code has println, what about that?